# Ships' stores or ship's stores?

Tags: orthography, possessives

How do I write this correctly?

When I use Google, 'ship's stores' seem to be used the most. But an [official government website from Canada](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-96-40/page-1.html) writes it as 'ships' stores'. Which is correct?

Thank you!

Comment: How many ships do you have?

Comment: It's about the stores of a single ship

Comment: That was quick, thank you. It's a bit odd because the link seems to be talking about a singular ship.

Comment: Many companies nowadays drop the apostrophe, and many consider this acceptable with 'non-ownership' associations/relationships. The plural form is then almost (but not completely) universal. So 'XYZ Chandlers sell ships stores'. / Many would retain the apostrophe for actual 'possessive' usage: On this plan of the Titanic you can see where the ship's stores were kept'. Obviously, if more than one ship is involved, ships' stores is required.